# Dual boot issue

Tags: ubuntu

I am installing Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 10. I have shrinked of  the hard disk upto 20 GB will it be ok ? Is there any need of ram distribution while installing it or it will detect by it's own? I have 4 gb of ram

Comment: Voting to close this question as Off-Topic due to hardware related issues.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely be okay since 10GB is sufficient for ubuntu. There is n

Comment: Thanks what about the RAM distribution?

Comment: You are either booting up windows or Linux. What do you mean by RAM distribution

Comment: you want to use virtual machine or dual boot? For virtual machine, you may need to consider the ram while it is not necessary to consider  about the ram for dual boot.

Comment: Ok i am having dual boot

Comment: Thanks for helping